# Is the visual design of Area 51 intended to appeal largely to geeks?

Tags: discussion, area-51, design

Space, aliens, freakin' unicorns. Area 51's all a bit geek-centric (making it inherently more male-oriented). However, aren't we supposed to be proposing sites for the internet community at large? Isn't that community pretty much 50/50 male to female and not entirely geeks?

I'm just a little concerned that there'll be very few sites for girls and women coming into existence, when such social knowledge-sharing is just as much a female thing as a male thing.

In short, can we change the theme, please?

Yes, I'm male and the current theme does appeal to me -- and I'm not saying there aren't geek girls out there -- but I still think we're missing an opportunity to engage a wider audience here.

Comment: ...unicorns largely appeal to men?

Comment: How would these mythical grrlz who think aliens are inherently sexist ever get to a site called Area51?  Would they mistake it for a luxury handbag maker or fashion designer label?

Comment: @Olafur actually a cooking site would be a pretty cool way to learn some stuff. I wonder if it's already proposed/exists

Comment: @Earlz: as Joel discussed in the "getting the topic/audience/scope right" post, "cooking" is too general and will overlap with the millions of other cooking sites out there.  A site targeted to people in the food service industry would be interesting (but over most of our heads, since we've established that that's not *our* industry) :)

Comment: @Earlz: [it does exist](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1288/food-and-cooking)  (ah, i see you found it) - I have high hopes for it, since many existing cooking sites are slow, ad-heavy, and... all too often I'm afraid... targeted more at people just looking for recipes. You know, the food equivalent of ExpertsExchange. "Cooking for engineers" is/was a good site, but more of a web-magazine with the usual hard-to-search PHPBB forums.

Comment: @Ether: "industry" sites are a whole 'nother ball game. SO isn't an "industry" site, it's a site about programming (albeit with a sizable minority who love nothing more than to sit around and chew the fat about their "industry").

Comment: @Shog: I mean "professional" -- while I'm sure some active SO members program just for fun, the vast majority of us do this professionally.

Comment: I'm guessing the down-votes on this question are because I've given the impression of being sexist. Sorry if that's the case. I really just wanted to raise the issue of the theme being more geek-friendly, and that led me to realise -- via various published stats (e.g. http://tinyurl.com/femaletech) -- that it would also mean the site's audience was primarily male. I just want to make sure the site reaches as wide an audience as possible, hence me raising the question. Please don't look badly upon me for it.

Comment: Oh, and the unicorns thing... as far as I can tell, that's Jeff's fetish. ;) Hence, it too is likely to be more of a geek thing, given his following. :)

Comment: @Mal Jeff has nothing to do with the unicorns. It's all Meta.

Comment: I'm sure a number of the downvotes (including my own) are because they don't agree that the theme is biased, not out of opinion of you. You were quite polite in bringing it up, so I don't think anyone thought that poorly of you. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-work

Comment: Ah, cheers for the link; first time posting here. I've got no problem with people disagreeing with me either, so that's all good. :)

Answer (score 16):

@Mal, I'm not sure I agree that the theme is *that* male-oriented.

I agree that "space stuff" generally skews more male in its audience, but these aren't exactly Ridley Scott / Babylon 5 aliens.

I actually think the whimsical nature of the artwork softens the site relative to say, any of the mainstream ones, which are highly efficient, but pretty cold and computer-y.

Comment: Agreed, the design never struck me as all that slanted.

Answer (score 7):

"Area 51's all a bit geek-centric (making it inherently more male-oriented)" I'm not even going to begin with that statement....

And I think that a woman would appreciate the art of the theme too. Personally I think it's one of the coolest themes I've seen on a website. If you want it taken down because you think it's sexist then I dare you to make a new theme that is as cool.

Comment: I'm sorry if that came across as me thinking the theme is sexist. That's absolutely not what I'm saying.

And as for the geek-implies-more-male thing, I'm not saying it that's how it should be -- assuming that's why you're taking offence. Instead, I'm merely trying to *openly* raise the issue of the male-to-female imbalance in the tech sector. Nothing more than that. (ref. http://tinyurl.com/femaletech)

Answer (score 6):

I don't think the visual design is the real problem.

Your question highlights a larger problem, which is: how do you allow new sites to grow organically out of Area51, when the people growing these sites are the same ones that are regular users of The Trilogy?

In other words, are the people currently proposing sites and voting on questions really representative of the general public?

Comment: no they're not representative at all.  But that route got tried and mostly didn't go that well, because not enough of that more diverse public came in to establish critical mass.  I think the (smart) idea here is to take the (non-representative) group that can be relied upon to embrace the medium to establish enough critical mass to sustain a site that can then support the broader (non-tech) public.   You'll start with only those sites that have decent techie appeal, but that will get non-geeks in, who will then embrace the system enough to start new sites, etc.

Comment: Also, the social networking element has been added (at least minimally) through the "share" selection after Following a proposal. If enough of _those_ get sent out, non-"trilogy" users should start to appear.

Comment: No, meta-folk are *not* representative of the general public. In this **really, early stage** we *want* people who are already familiar with the engine to try it out. Diversity comes later.

Comment: Fair enough. :)

Answer (score 6):

It's not a question of male or female oriented, but it is certainly geek oriented, oriented to technie types of either gender.  This may make sense to draw in the stackoverflow/superuser/serverfault crowd, but if the the goal of stack exchange is to make question answering better for the whole internet, it is way off the mark, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I don't consider myself a geek (I don't feel I'm smart enough)  but I like the visual design: Greetings Earthlings.

But I was more concerned with learning about what the section had to offer, offering suggestions, etc.

So there's at least one woman who likes the visual design of Area 51. ;)